# ¿Cómo indicar caducidad en mensaje push desde firebase functions?

Tags: firebase

Tengo el codigo que muestro a continuación y queria ver si podia indicar la caducidad del mensaje tal como se realiza en la consola pero no he encontrado como.

¿Es posible indicar caducidad?
¿Es posible posponer la fecha de envio a una determinada?

Gracias.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.updateNoticias = functions.firestore
    .document('messages/push')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {
      const newValue = change.after.data();
        const payload = {
          notification: {
            title: 'Nuevo mensaje',
            body: '' + newValue.mensaje 
          }
        };
        var topic = 'topic';

          admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, payload)
        .then(function(response) {
          console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log("Error sending message:", error);
        });
});
```

Comment: podrias explicar con mas detalle que quieres realizar :D ?

Comment: podrías posponer la fecha del envío desde donde se emite la orden, con algún manejador de fechas como moment, pones el dia y la hora y luego mediante un condicionate `if` mandas la instrucción el momento que tu quieras, por otro lado el tiempo de vida de la notificación lo agregas mediante la llave `ttl`, y es un atributo que esta al mismo nivel de tu key `notification`.
Saludos.